# Identify users without a login

Tags: android

I have an app that sends user location data to the server using webview load html. Since the users are truck drivers I do not expect them to know to login using password and user name every time they use app , so my solution is to for each user to make an app with it's own user name and password embedded into the app using the id field sent to the php page .

```
`enter code here`url="http://mywebsite.php?id=16"+"&longitude="+longitude+"&latitude="+latitude+"&brzina="+speed+"&vreme="+cal.getTime()+"&datum="+date;
```

What I am changing in url is the id field sent to php page .
Is there a way for me to automate the creation of Android apps without compiling app every time I have to provide a new app to the driver .Let 's say I am given a list of drivers with their id numbers I put this some were and I get for 15 drivers 15 android apps all with the different id part in url .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need to know the ID before they connect for the first time?

If not, you can store a GUID on the phone, which is created on first time run. as an identifier. And when the GUID comes in to the server for the first time, you log them as a new user with that ID, and from then on, know its them again.

for generating a GUID I recommend [the UUID class](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/UUID.html)

and storing/retrieving it, maybe the [SharedPreferences Class.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Alternatively, give them a GUID in an ini file, which your app runs off. (which you know the ID before hand.)

Comment: You gave me a good idea I could ask user to login to web site only the first time insert user data into sqlite database and later on if the row is present use the id from sqlite .It is a good idea .Thanks!

Comment: @JovoKrneta Glad to hear it. Consider upvoting / marking my answer as the solution in return. :) Thanks.

Comment: @JovoKrneta Yea thanks :) Can always press the up arrow too :D Heh.